# Images generated with 96dpi in local but 72dpi in server

Tags: php, server, gd, intervention

I am using Intervention Image library which uses GD or Imagemagick (GD in my case).

When I generate a PNG of several pictures on my local machine, the image is generated with 96dpi, but when I upload the code to the server and create the same composition with the same images I get a 72dpi image. This breaks my calculations as I need for that image to be 100cm X 70cm.

I tried increasing the PHP memory limit to 512MB on the server (I have 128MB locally).

I can't understand why the dpi is different.

There's more logic to create the canvas, but these are the basic lines.

```
// Default size of final canvas 100x70cm
$canvasWidth = 3780;
$canvasHeight = 2646;
$offsetStep = 196;

// Create the canvas
$img_canvas = Image::canvas($canvasWidth, $canvasHeight, '#fff');
$imgPath = Image::make(storage_path() . '/clients/v1/' . $codigoCampaña . '/' . $image->folder_id . '/' . $image->image);
$img_canvas->insert($imgPath, 'top-left', $initialOffsetX, $initialOffsetY);
$img_canvas->save($previewPath . $previewSmallName, 100);
$img_canvas->destroy();
```

Comment: why would the image dpi setting be even remotely related to the PHP memory allocation? Show the code you're using to trigger gd/im, otherwise we can't really tell what you're doing, and thus can't help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need that image to be 100cm x 70cm"*? That is the size of a piece of paper but you are displaying it on a screen, not a piece of paper. Screens and the web work in pixels not centimetres - else how would the picture fit in an iPhone screen?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers ignore DPI. DPI doesn’t apply to layout on the web. DPI only matters in print. Focus on resolution. That's what matters.

A pixel (which is short for “picture element”) is the smallest unit of measure on a grid displaying a digital image. DPI measures how big those pixels, or dots, are when they’re printed.

Also, browsers do not work in inches or centimeters. They work in pixels. Width & Height.

Comment: Yeah, I need the image to be 100cm x 70cm but I put the pixels with 96dpi in mind, so if the system gives me a 72dpi image, when the user is going to print the file it won't have the 100cm x 70cm it should right? I need the picture to save with 96dpi in the server as it does in my local. Other approach would be calculate the pixels for 72dpi but I will lost quality right?

Comment: You need to offer a downloadable version for printing. Store the 300DPI image in a zip file, PSD, TIFF etc. When an image displays in your browser the DPI is reduced to the native of the browser (generally 72dpi).

Comment: Also, If i remember correctly the dpi of an image will stay intact if you export as pdf in photoshop.

Comment: But I am not displaying the image in the browser, It is being downloaded directly. From my local with 96dpi but from my server 72dpi

Comment: in web format I assume? Upload a 96 dpi image to your server via FTP and then download it via FTP. Open it in Photoshop or other image editor. Check DPI. Next, Open it in the browser > save as whatever and check DPI. You can also view the image directly via url and check DPI.